# `easygui` - dialogs are not given focus when created

Tags: python, easygui

I am using Python 2.7.9, `easygui 0.97.4`, and Windows 7.

I am trying to pop up a dialog box using the following:

```
import easygui
easygui.msgbox()
```

I would expect a dialog box to pop up and come to the foreground, taking focus. Sometimes, this happens. Other times, the dialog box does not come to the front, and spawns behind all other windows.

Whether the dialog box comes to the front, or hides behind other windows, seems to depend on something unpredictable. Giving different arguments to `easygui.msgbox()` doesn't seem to help. Restarting the Python interpreter sometimes makes it work, and sometimes doesn't.

The issue is not so bad for simple dialogs, which at least give a flashing button in the task bar to get your attention.

[image]

It is worse for `diropenbox()` which does not spawn a flashing button in the taskbar. The dialog spawns behind a window and gives no evidence it's  there, until you minimise all other windows.

[image]

[image]

How can I force `easygui` dialogs to always come to the front and always take focus, instead of hiding behind other windows?

I have perused the [Github robertlugg/easygui](https://github.com/robertlugg/easygui) issue tracker and there don't seem to be any open bug reports for this issue.

---

Edit: I have opened a bug report - https://github.com/robertlugg/easygui/issues/76 .

Comment: i'd be interested to find out if you received a response to your bug report. i'm using the latest version of easygui, and still experiencing the described behavior.